# Equal-Power Crossfade in AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction

Tags: ios, swift, avvideocomposition, avcomposition

How can I get an equal-power crossfade working in an `AVVideoComposition`? I'm using something like the following to fade between video tracks, but when looping the same video over and over there is a very noticeable brightness dip during the transition due to whatever curve is being used internally in `setOpacityRamp`.

```swift
let videoInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

let fromLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: fromCompositionTrack)
fromLayerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1, toEndOpacity: 0, timeRange: timeRange)

let toLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: toCompositionTrack)
toLayerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 0, toEndOpacity: 1, timeRange: timeRange)

videoInstruction.timeRange = timeRange
videoInstruction.layerInstructions = [fromLayerInstruction, toLayerInstruction]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t possible. The `setOpacityRamp` methods for `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` lists the following description:

> During an opacity ramp, opacity is computed using a **linear** interpolation.

There is an easier solution, though, which I found in the book [Learning AV Foundation: A Hands-on Guide to Mastering the AV Foundation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OVMUBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA353&ots=u3HzIauvfQ&dq=avvideocomposition%20z%20index&pg=PA357#v=onepage&q=implementing%20a%20simple%20dissolve%20transition%20is%20easy&f=false) — fade out the current video track, but don’t fade in the new one. The book refers to this as a plain *dissolve* rather than a *cross dissolve*.

```swift
let videoInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

let fromLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: fromCompositionTrack)
fromLayerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 1, toEndOpacity: 0, timeRange: timeRange)

let toLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: toCompositionTrack)
// toLayerInstruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: 0, toEndOpacity: 1, timeRange: timeRange)

videoInstruction.timeRange = timeRange
videoInstruction.layerInstructions = [fromLayerInstruction, toLayerInstruction]
```